# useState is blank Pressable onPress

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

Getting some odd behaviour I really don't understand. It is a simple form I've created with a submit button. I can see the state being set as I type into the boxes, however when I click the Pressable it comes out as **reset**. I'm not sure how linked it is to react-native it seems like more of a react thing but for what it is worth I'm using React-Native and Expo.

My logs look something like this as I type "Kfc" and "15" in the two boxes.

Cheers in advance!

```json
state {"amount": "", "title": ""}
state {"amount": "", "title": "K"}
state {"amount": "", "title": "Kf"}
state {"amount": "", "title": "Kfc"}
state {"amount": "1", "title": "Kfc"}
state {"amount": "15", "title": "Kfc"}
state {"amount": "", "title": ""}
```

```js
const ManualTransactionPage = ({ tabId }: {tabId: string}) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>("Kfc");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState<string>("15");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("state", {
      title: name,
      amount,
    });
  }, [name, amount]);

  const handleAddTransaction = () => {
    console.log("state", {
      title: name,
      amount,
    });
  };

  return (
    <View className="pt-5 mx-3">
      <TextInput
        className="w-full bg-white rounded-xl text-2xl mb-4 px-3 py-4"
        value={name}
        onChangeText={setName}
        placeholder="KFC"
      />
      <TextInput
        className="w-full bg-white rounded-xl text-2xl mb-4 px-3 py-4"
        value={amount}
        onChangeText={setAmount}
        placeholder="9.99"
      />
      <Pressable
        onPress={handleAddTransaction}
        className="flex flex-row justify-center mt-5 group"
      >
        <ButtonStyling>
          <Text className="text-white text-xl px-3">Add</Text>
        </ButtonStyling>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};
```

**Edit**

One clarification, its not really a reset because the inputs still hold the correct values. Just the onPress handler can't see them.

**Update**

It has something to do with the Pressable onPress function. I tried the same thing with a side by side  component and it works fine. I've also learnt something else that maybe its something to do with closures? New to me! Still figuring out how to get it working with

Comment: I had to comment out the `ButtonStyling` component since I can't see what it is/does, but otherwise your code runs as expected. Here's a running [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/usestate-is-blank-pressable-onpress) demo of your code. Feel free to fork the snack and add more of your actual code to see if you can create a ***running*** demo we could inspect live.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there might be an issue with the asynchronous nature of state updates in your React Native component. I suggest modifying your code by creating separate functions (handleNameChange and handleAmountChange) to handle state changes. These functions first log the current state to the console and then update the corresponding state. This adjustment may help resolve the unexpected behavior you're experiencing. Good luck!

```js
const ManualTransactionPage = ({ tabId }: {tabId: string}) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>("Kfc");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState<string>("15");

  const handleNameChange = (text: string) => {
    console.log("state", {
      title: text,
      amount,
    });
    setName(text);
  };

  const handleAmountChange = (text: string) => {
    console.log("state", {
      title: name,
      amount: text,
    });
    setAmount(text);
  };

  const handleAddTransaction = () => {
    console.log("state", {
      title: name,
      amount,
    });
  };

  return (
    <View className="pt-5 mx-3">
      <TextInput
        className="w-full bg-white rounded-xl text-2xl mb-4 px-3 py-4"
        value={name}
        onChangeText={handleNameChange}
        placeholder="KFC"
      />
      <TextInput
        className="w-full bg-white rounded-xl text-2xl mb-4 px-3 py-4"
        value={amount}
        onChangeText={handleAmountChange}
        placeholder="9.99"
      />
      <Pressable
        onPress={handleAddTransaction}
        className="flex flex-row justify-center mt-5 group"
      >
        <ButtonStyling>
          <Text className="text-white text-xl px-3">Add</Text>
        </ButtonStyling>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};
```

More details here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

Comment: Sadly didn't help, I think one clarification (which I added to the post) is that its not really a reset because the inputs still hold the correct values. Just the onPress handler can't see the updated ones.